# Angular $routeProvider specify valid values for named group (regex?)

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

My problem is I have a controller that should be loaded if the first path argument is a valid "sorting" value e.g.

```
/date
/name
```

Otherwise it should load my error page.

My routeProvider entry looks like this:

```
$routeProvider.
        when('/:sort', {
            controller: 'myCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: 'error.html'
        });
```

My problem is the controller will be loaded no matter what value is given

```
'/name' loads the controller so does '/asdf'
```

/asdf should load the error page.

My Question is there any way to specify valid values (with regex maybe) for the named group or must I specify multiple routeProvider entries e.g.

```
$routeProvider.
        when('/date', {
            controller: 'myCtrl'
        })
        when('/name', {
            controller: 'myCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: 'error.html'
        });
```

Follow up question if this is the only solution:

In my controller I retrieve the value of :sort using routeParams, and it's very convenient.

If I were to not use a named group and instead have a $routeProvider entry for every valid sort value, the value of sort will not be included in $routeParams.

Do I have to then parse the path to get the correct sort value or is there a more straightforward way?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

$routeChangeStart is what you are looking for !

Just take a look at the documention for [$route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route), whenever a route change, this event will occur.

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
  //next is the next route information and current the current route.

 // if regex.dontMatch(next) then redirect else don't do anything
});
```

where regex.dontMatch is your regex function